# Add a not empty check for a date field into a query

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to alter this query so that it would check if frp_fundraisingprogram.start_date is not empty or contains the default value?

```
SELECT frp_fundraisingprogram.id AS id 
FROM frp_fundraisingprogram  
WHERE frp_fundraisingprogram.start_date <= DATE_ADD(UTC_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL - 2 day) 
  AND frp_fundraisingprogram.date_entered > '2015-04-09 16:55:18' 
  AND NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM aow_processed 
      WHERE aow_processed.aow_workflow_id='9bc1bb2e-cd5a-5c75-cc68-5526ae30331e' 
      AND aow_processed.parent_id=frp_fundraisingprogram.id 
      AND aow_processed.status = 'Complete' AND aow_processed.deleted = 0) 
  AND frp_fundraisingprogram.deleted = 0
```

Comment: Which do you want, to check if the value is empty/null or contains a default value? Is the field nullable?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

Just include that in your where clause...

```
`...WHERE not isnull(frp_fundraisingprogram.start_date)
AND frp_fundraisingprogram.start_date != '0000-00-00 ...`
```

That is if you are trying to exclude these records.  You can reverse the logic if you only want these records to show up.